# Как работает i % 2 в list comprehension и почему оно работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Вот код:

```
def alternate(n, first_value, second_value):
    return [[first_value, second_value][i % 2] for i in range(n)]



if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(alternate(5, True, False))
```

Как и почему в функции alternate работает `[i%2]`. Когда я убрал `[i % 2]` то появились квадратные скобки и код распечатал `[[True, False], [True, False], [True, False], [True, False], [True, False]]`.
А когда `[i % 2]` стоит там то код печатает
`[True, False, True, False, True]`

Comment: `%` — это остаток от деления, при делении на 2 остаток бывает только 0 или 1, `[first_value, second_value]` это список с двумя элементами, `[i % 2]` достаёт первый или второй элемент списка в зависимости от того, является ли `i` чётным или нечётным

Comment: И list comprehension тут ни при чём, ничто не мешает написать то же самое в обычном цикле `for i in range(n): result.append([first_value, second_value][i % 2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение `[i % 2]` в данном случае является индексом списка `[first_value, second_value]`, и при получении некоторого `i` из списка выбирается соответствующий элемент.

Иными словами, если мы уберём `[i % 2]`, то мы получим генерацию списка, в который будут `i` раз добавляться списки `[first_value, second_value]` (здесь — `[True, False]`). А если мы не будем убирать данный индекс, то, в зависимости от `i`, из вышеуказанного списка будет выбираться либо `True`, либо `False`, и помещаться в новый список.